# Which interpolation technique is suitable for a bathymetry of a small lake?

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, bathymetry, lakes

This is a lake of approximately 13 ha with 81 sampled depth points in about 10 transect lines:

[image: Sampled points]

Previously in ARCgis with a 50 ha lake and about a 100 depth sampling points, I got decent output with the `TopotoRaster` tool. However, no such exact equivalent seems to exist with QGIS or open source software.

In QGIS, I got the interpolated raster below, using the TIN method in the Raster Interpolation plugin. However, this seemed to be a lucky outcome, when I tried to repeat, I got different results (unsatisfactory) in spite of not really varying any parameter.

[image: Interpolated raster]

These are more urban (constructed) tanks than lakes, therefore, they are fairly regular in their bed profile, hence the low point sampling density. Some articles seemed to suggest Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) as the most suitable technique, yet I seemed to get the worst results with that (possibly owing to low point density).

Are there any heuristics which can be employed here considering the size of the lake, its regular profile and the point sampling density to arrive at which interpolation method is apt? (between Kriging, IDW, Bilinear, Cubic convolution, TIN or spline)

Or is it always a bit of trial and error?

Comment: Intuitively, I would think interpolation with Nearest Neighbour makes the most sense since the differences in depths are relatively regular. It would be great if anyone could suggest a resource where some procedures/guidelines are outlined to make sure that consistent output is achieved with respect to interpolation of this kind and in other cases too.

Comment: Reefmaster creates good looking contours and shaded relief with TIN http://reefmaster.com.au/index.php/forum/support/909-interpolation-algorithm#6242.

Comment: By looking at the image QGIS don't utilize the boundary automatically. I would add a bunch of points with zero depth along the boundary.

Comment: There seem to be sample points outside the boundary, so I suspect either the boundary is wrong or there's an uncertainty in the bathymetry locations.

Comment: IDW is best when you have a relatively dense set of points over your study area, but you suggest it has a low point density.  In this case maybe Splining is a good option,  it smooths the surface out which I imagine is how a lake bottom looks (but i really dont know) "Conceptually, it is analogous to bending a sheet of rubber to pass through known points while minimizing the total curvature of the surface. This method is best for gently varying surfaces, such as elevation, water table heights, or pollution concentrations." -http://www.gisresources.com/types-interpolation-methods_3/

Comment: What parameters did you use to get the image shown? You mention "I got different results (unsatisfactory) in spite of not really varying any parameter" ... please specify (click 'edit' to change post) and indicate what you changed and why the results were unsatisfactory.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend a technique without knowing why you want the depths. For example, if you want to compute the volume of the lake then you might need a different method than if you just want to construct a map of the regions that a boat with a 5ft draught should avoid.

Comment: @user30184 Checked out reefmaster, looks like it can create visually appealing bathymetry outputs, but it is commercial/paid software.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, previously for another lake I had done this, but out of curiosity, is there any way/tool in qgis where you can specify a shoreline like in TopotoRaster (arcgis)? Also I felt like adding 0 points is somewhat different than adding a 0 contour/shoreline, any thoughts?

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for pointing out boundary issue. Its more that boundary was digitized using google Earth, and soundings were done in a boat with physical access to water, yielding slight differences extending beyond boundary. I suppose if shoreline was also digitized using GPS points, there would be more consistency.

Comment: @ed.hank Thanks for quoted explanation on splining, I like how it is conceptually illustrated. Will try out splining and add results to my question edits.

Comment: @Simbamangu parameters were defaults set by interpolation tool, since I didn't really have an informed basis for altering any of them besides the extent. I will try to add a screenshot/details in edits.

Comment: @Spacedman Volume is pretty much the goal, and ultimately the interpolation and resultant bathymetry informs a water balance for the lake. Spline still stands as apt technique?

Comment: Your question was "Which interpolation technique is suitable for a bathymetry of a small lake" and I used Reefmaster as a reference meaning to say "some folks get good looking results with TIN and some smoothing".  TIN was my  point, not Reefmaster, and open source software utilising TIN method in a clever way should make as good output.

Comment: @user30184 I see, that may have been implicit, but became clear only when you explained it in your last comment, thanks for the suggestion on tweaking TIN

Answer (score 10):

One alternative is [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) as suggested in the related post: 
[Interpolation of multibeam bathymetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67113/interpolation-of-multibeam-bathymetry/67125#67125).

From QGIS, use the GRASS tool [`v.surf.rst`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.surf.rst.html):

> Performs surface interpolation from vector points map by splines.

Then, you can test different types of parameterization available within the tool. There is an option to apply a leave-one-out cross validation for parameter optimization, which will vary gradually the tension, smoothing, etc; in order to find the minimal predictive error.

As suggested by user30184, make sure the input dataset uses ground level points at the lake's boundaries, so to avoid extrapolation.

Comment: Spline is what I used on a River Bathymetry project I did as a contractor for USGS. I never asked exactly why but we were pleased with the results. I almost made a similar answer but I wasn't sure of the justification. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks Andre, really appreciate your quick and crisp answer. I had some trouble trying to run v.surf.rst, it refused within QGIS to give me any proper raster output with values. Suspect its some problems with the way I have projected data. When I figure it out I will put the results in the edits to the question.