# Interpolating sparse bathymetry to correct global grid using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, bathymetry, spline, multibeam

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

I am trying to update a global bathymetry grid (at 1 min resolution) with local sounding data (resampled to 1 min resolution). The sounding data is sparse and irregular in coverage (criss-crossing lines across the area). I would like to correct the global grid with the ship sounding data. Rather than just replace the global values by the local ones, I would like to correct the global grid with the local soundings interpolated over a larger scale. I have tried spline in tension interpolation over the entire study area but the output was patchy.

I have also tried to follow the methodology from Jeffrey Evans in this post:
[Interpolation of multibeam bathymetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67113/interpolation-of-multibeam-bathymetry) but I was unable to figure out how to filter the data using a Gaussian weighted filter.

My question is - How can I smooth a patchy spline interpolated map with a Gaussian filter (sigma = 2) so that the interpolated region is significant within 2 standard deviations of the original sampling point?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, ask one question per post